# error C2784 in recursive functions of my BinarySearch Tree c++ could not deduce template argument

Tags: c++, function, recursion

I am getting the following error for both my recursive functions. I cant seem to find the problem myself. If anyone could help me Id appreciate it.

Error   3   error C2784: 'void Insert(TreeNode *&,ItemType)' : could not deduce template argument for 'TreeNode *&' from 'ItemType *'

Error   1   error C2784: 'void Destroy(TreeNode *&)' : could not deduce template argument for 'TreeNode *&' from 'ItemType *'

```
template <class ItemType>
void Destroy(TreeNode<ItemType>*& tree)

{
    if (tree != NULL)
  {
    Destroy(tree->left);

    Destroy(tree->right);
    delete tree;

  }
}

template <class ItemType>
void Insert(TreeNode<ItemType>*& tree, ItemType item)
{
    if (tree == NULL)
    {           // Insertion place found.
        tree = new TreeNode<ItemType>;
        tree->right = NULL;
        tree->left = NULL;
        tree->info = item;
    }
    else if (item < tree->info)
    Insert(tree->left, item);                       // Insert in left subtree.
else
    Insert(tree->right, item);                      // Insert in right subtree.
}


template<class ItemType>
struct TreeNode
{
    ItemType info;
    ItemType* left;
    ItemType* right;
};


template<class ItemType>
void TreeType<ItemType>::InsertItem(ItemType item)
{
    Insert(root, item);
}


template<class ItemType>
TreeType<ItemType>::~TreeType()
{
    Destroy(root);
}
```

Comment: Show us where you're using Insert/Destroy and the definition of TreeNode

Comment: Aren't you missing the template<class ItemType> at the Insert function?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put

```
template <class ItemType>
```

before the definition of `Insert`. Also you forgot the semicolon after the closing brace of `Destroy`. When I fixed these errors, the thing compiled under GCC 4.9.

Answer (score 0):

Insert/Destroy are both Helper functions. The errors only occur when I use the functions.

```
template<class ItemType>
void TreeType<ItemType>::InsertItem(ItemType item)
{
    Insert(root, item);
}


template<class ItemType>
TreeType<ItemType>::~TreeType()
{
    Destroy(root);

}
```

Comment: Update your problem description with this instead of answering your own question